# How can I separate the sequential print statements from nested for-loops?

Tags: c#, for-loop, code-separation

I have the following method which prints out all the contiguous subsets of the given array. I want to be able to separate out the ugly print statement interwoven in the for loops and into a new function. Is this doable?

```
    // Example:  
    // Input: char[] input = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    // Output: 
    //        (a) (a b) (a b c)
    //        (b) (b c)
    //        (c)  

    static void  PrintContSubArrays(char[] arr)
    {
        int len = arr.Length;
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= len; j++)
            {
                sb2.AppendFormat("(");

                for (int k = i; k < j; k++)
                {
                    sb2.AppendFormat("{0} ", arr[k]);
                }

                sb2.Remove(sb2.Length - 1, 1);
                sb2.Append(") ");

                if (sb2.Length > 3) sb1.Append(sb2);
                sb2.Clear();
            }
            sb1.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb1.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Can you write a desired outcome, what would the function do and how it would be called?

Comment: What print are you talking about? The string builder appends?

Comment: @usr Yes, in the current implementation, the stringbuilder collects the characters and prints it at the end. I would like to do away with the sb statements.

Comment: @Andrei The outcome should be the same as it is right now. I want to be able to call the function and print the outcome on the console as the function currently does, but somehow, send the characters from the array to a different function that takes care of formatting and printing the final outcome. I am not sure if this is even doable - or if I am making any sense. Please let me know if this is still not clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Implemented this based on suggestion by @usr

> Instead of doing the string processing inline extract the subarrays as
>   `char[]` and return them using `yield return`. That way the caller
>   receives a stream of subarrays. He can process, format and print them
>   as he wants.

This is what I have. But this does not translate to your exact output format. Some formatting is lost due to loss of context. If you are willing to pass in the original array length into the print method, you could get exactly what you need by tweaking the for-loop in print method.

```
    // Input: int[] input = new int[] { 1, 2, 3};
    // Call: Console.WriteLine(PrintContSubArrays(GetContSubArrays(input)));
    // Output: 
    //       (1)
    //       (1 2)
    //       (1 2 3)
    //       (2)
    //       (2 3)
    //       (3)

    // Generate subsets
    static IEnumerable<int[]> GetContSubArrays(int[] arr)
    {
        int len = arr.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= len; j++)
            {
                int[] placeholder = new int[j - i < 0 ? 0 : j - i];
                bool isPlaceholderEmpty = true;

                for (int k = i; k < j; k++)
                {
                    placeholder[k - i] = arr[k];
                    isPlaceholderEmpty = false;
                }
                if (!isPlaceholderEmpty) yield return placeholder;
            }
        }
    }

    // Print
    static string PrintContSubArrays(IEnumerable<int[]> input)
    {
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (int[] intarr in input)
        {
            if (intarr != null)
            {
                sb1.Append("(");
                foreach (int intsingle in intarr)
                {
                    sb1.AppendFormat("{0} ", intsingle);
                }
                sb1.Remove(sb1.Length - 1, 1);
                sb1.Append(")");
            }
            sb1.AppendFormat(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        return sb1.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the string processing inline extract the subarrays as `char[]` and return them using `yield return`. That way the caller receives a stream of subarrays. He can process, format and print them as he wants.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to simplify things:

```
static void PrintContiguousSubArrays( char[] input )
{
  if ( input == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("input") ;
  if ( input.Length == 0 ) return ;

  for ( int offset = 0 ; offset < input.Length ; ++offset )
  {
    string separator = "" ;

    for ( int length = 1 ; offset+length <= input.Length ; ++length )
    {
      Console.Write( "{0}[{1}]" ,
        separator ,
        string.Join("," , input.Skip(offset).Take(length).Select( c => new string(c,1) ) )
        );
      separator = " ";
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

  }

  return ;
}
```

Here's another way:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>> ContiguousSubArraysOf( char[] input )
{
  if ( input == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("input") ;

  for ( int offset = 0 ; offset < input.Length ; ++offset )
  {
    for ( int length = 1 ; offset+length <= input.Length ; ++length )
    {
      yield return input.Skip(offset).Take(length) ;
    }
  }

}
```

This will let you say something like this:

```
char[] input = "abc".ToCharArray();

foreach( var item in ContiguousSubArraysOf(input) )
{
  Console.WriteLine( "[{0}]" ,
    string.Join( "," , item.Select( c => new string(c,1) ) )
  ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about doing this?

```
static void PrintContSubArrays(char[] arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            from n1 in Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length)
            select String.Join(" ",
                from n2 in Enumerable.Range(1, arr.Length - n1)
                select String.Format("({0})", String.Join(" ", arr.Skip(n1).Take(n2))))));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This way you can get rid of all of the ugly loops too.

Comment: +1 for the elegant code! I think this is the best alternative to the code presented. But, the OP is asking for separating the core operation and print action.